# Combinatorial Methods in Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, big-list

There are a lot of examples of cases where linear algebra is used to solve problem in combinatorics. For example, the [Friendship Theorem](http://math.mit.edu/~fox/MAT307-lecture20.pdf) and 
[Fisher's Inequality.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_inequality) In fact, there is a whole subject dedicated to this, namely Algebraic Combinatorics.

My question is what are some examples of combinatorics being used to solve linear algebra problems?

Comment: Do you know matroid theory?

Comment: @CarryonSmiling: I have heard of it but I'm not really familiar with it.

Comment: If you think Representation Theory is linear algebra ( I do ), then yes a lot.  For example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_tableau#Applications_in_representation_theory

Comment: Maybe the link between Young tableaux, partitions of integers and Jordan normal forms of endomorphisms can interest you.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the efficiency of the [Coppersmith-Winograd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coppersmith%E2%80%93Winograd_algorithm) multiplication algorithm relies on the existence of a sufficiently dense subset of $[1,N]$ that is a [Sidon set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sidon_sequence). That is a well-studied problem in combinatorics: Rusza proved, for sufficiently large $N$s, the existence of a Sidon subset of $[1,N]$ with at least $N^{\sqrt{2}-1-\varepsilon}$ elements by exploiting the binary representations of the logarithms of some primes.

Answer (score 1):

A little late reply, but aanother example is perhaps the Permanent Lemma, which is an application of the Combinatorial Nullstellensatz.